# Qt library linking error

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I have this headers in my class

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <mmreg.h>
#include <msacm.h>
#include <wmsdk.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "msacm32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "wmvcore.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "winmm.lib")
#pragma intrinsic(memset,memcpy,memcmp)
```

When i try to use the function `CreateStreamOnHGlobal(mp3HGlobal, FALSE, &mp3Stream);` i get this error:

```
playlist.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__CreateStreamOnHGlobal@12 referenced in function "public: int __thiscall Playlist::getLengthInSeconds(class QString)" (?getLengthInSeconds@Playlist@@QAEHVQString@@@Z)
```

I've tried to add the `msacm32.lib` but I found that exist under the name `MSAcm32.lib` and Qt doesn't recognize it; also with `winmm.lib`, who has the name `WinMM.lib`. I don't know what to add, what to do so that my program to work. What can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by

> Qt doesn't recognize it

you mean that the linker error is not resolved, the following may help.

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378980(v=vs.85).aspx you should also be linking to `Ole32.lib` for `CreateStreamOnHGlobal`. If after adding ole32.lib other linker errors occur, a quick google or MSDN search will show you which lib files are missing.

Also, FYI windows is not case-sensitive.

Comment: I try to add Ole32.lib with add library..., i've tried external, system, but when i select it, the name is with red and I can't press next. What could be the problem? The compiler si Visual Studio. I have the same program(function) written in Visual Studio and it works.